# Why is my iPhone UIToolBar so large when coming back to my view controller?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitoolbar

I have a UIToolbar in Xcode that I'm creating dynamically with 2 BarButtonItems that behave exactly as expected when I first go to the page, but if i back up and come back, the UIToolbar takes up the entire frame area.

The behavior should be no UIToolbar until I hit the edit button, at which time, it shows up on the bottom.  If I hit the cancel button, the UIToolbar goes away.  This works perfect.  Once, I hit the back button, and click the button to send me to this view again, the UIToolbar has taken over.  I can still hit the edit button, where the UIToolbar becomes the little one on the bottom.  If I hit the cancel, it goes away all together.  Then I can click edit and it continues to be the intended view.  The only time it's an issue is when i first load the view for the second, third, etc. time.

I almost feel like it was never properly released or something.  I do call the removeFromSuperview on viewWillDisappear method.

Answer (score 0):

simply you have to declare the object on class level (in interface) batter for you to `@synthesize` them, perform action in `viewDidLoad` then use the button to animate the `UIView`

Answer (score 0):

Here setFrame of `UIToolBar` in `viewWillAppear:` method and also add as a subview of your `self.view` if you remove `UIToolBar` in `viewWillDisappear:`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [yourToolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];// set frame which you want
}
```

Comment: where are you saying to add the subview?  Right now I have that in viewwilldisappear- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [actionToolbar removeFromSuperview];
}

Comment: sorry, here's my viewdidappear    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.view.superview addSubview:actionToolbar];
}

Comment: @user1877746 you try with the viewWillAppear?? and exactly whats the problem and what u want dude..?